# Which software do you use for facial expression analysis?

Tags: usability-testing, user-research, api

Dear incredible community, I am once again in need of your help.

***Summary: Looking for a tool to analyze participant's webcam feed to produce a report of facial expressions - it does not have to be real-time.***

I am trying to pitch remote usability testing (as opposed to lab testing) to my boss, and am looking for a tool to overcome our inability to observe nonverbal communication.

What I am looking for is a tool that will analyze the participant's webcam feed to produce a report of facial expressions - it does not have to be real-time.

I am thinking that we could use this report as "bookmarks", using distinct expressions as a sign of positive/negative reaction to the interface to produce a list of interactions that are working well for us, or in need of change.

[I found this list of APIs](http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-50-face-detection-recognition-apis), but non of the websites provided all the information I required (I did contact several of them, and am waiting for a reply).

Does anyone have any experience with such a tool and could recommend it?

Answer (score 1):

I personally dont have experience with a tool but a quick google search turned up a number of tools namely

1. [Face Reader by Noldus](http://www.noldus.com/human-behavior-research/products/facereader)
2. [Affdex Facial coding](http://www.affdex.com/)
3. [Facet Vision](http://www.emotient.com/)

Here is an [analysis of how effective facereader](http://www.allaboutux.org/facereader) is

> FaceReader constructs a model of the face from the video and
>   automatically evaluate several elementary facial movements (action
>   units). Based on these movements it calculates the likeliness that
>   each of six basic emotions (joy, anger, sadness, surprise, fear and
>   disgust) is felt at any given time. Tests from the provider of the
>   software indicate a success rate of up to 90% with frontal face
>   images.
>
> **Weaknesses** Data limited to six basic emotions.
>
> The video has to be captured during a test with a real product,
>   limiting the usefulness of FaceReader in the early stages of the
>   design process.

That said, facial expression analysis is not a refined science and your experience might be more of a hit or a miss. To quote this [article](http://www.trinidad.ee/blog/neuro-ux-smoke-and-mirrors-or-the-future-of-user-experience-research-aga-bojko-associate-director-user-centric-inc/)

> EmoVision dashboard is one of the possibilities of facial recognition
>   for analyzing purposes. People can be sad and puzzled, neutral and
>   happy, even surprised. This kind of software recognizes the subject`s
>   emotions and lets us analyze them further. It will also generate a
>   suitable graph.
>
> FaceReader dashboard is useful on measuring overall emotional
>   Intensity on scale of 0 to 1, but often enough a lot of emotions are
>   going on at the same time and the software can only detect the
>   strongest of them. The problem with these kinds of applications is
>   that they are not ready yet.
>
> **During measurements, the subjects need to be completely still and must
>   not talk or move their head. Facial touching is generally not allowed
>   and this method does not work well with glasses. It requires more
>   lighting and only recognizes the simplest and strongest of emotions.
>   Subtle emotions are ignored.**

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the question but a bit of background psychology:

It's worth bearing in mind that there are learnt social rules which vary with cultures on whether people 'display' their emotions:

These are known as **[Display Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_rules)s**

One of the bottom lines of this is that people's expressed emotions may vary if they think they are in a 'social context' (ie being observed)

Paul Ekman did quite a lot of work on this, particularly on the issue of how the rules [vary between cultures.](http://www.paulekman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/American-Japanese-Cultural-Differences-In-Intensity-Ratings-.pdf)

Comment: That's an interesting point to definitely consider when conducting international studies.

From the little I know, there is a cross-culture baseline for most common expressions, how distinct the expression is, however, will vary between cultures.

Interesting enough, [a blind person uses the same facial expressions as a sighted one!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4Oed7K7M9s).

Thank you for the link! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

HcaLong participated with a company that made something similar and worked great, maybe you can contact them, can not remember which was the link the study, but you can look inside your web http://preparatumente.com